# How large would an uncompressed 10^9 * 10^9 white image file be?

Tags: image

Is there some way to determine file size based on the content of the uncompressed image?

Comment: No file format I know of can store such an image. If you change the question to 1e4^2 it becomes more answerable.

Comment: I just meant a 1 billion by 1 billion pixel image.

Comment: If the image is completely uncompressed, i.e. stored as pixels. Then the answer is just the number of  pixels times the size of each.

Comment: depends on the format - svg can be pretty small.

Comment: Approximately 10^18.  If each pixel were the size of a football field, you could not fit all of them on a postage stamp.